# ASP.NET Entity Framework Order By and Then By not working

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have this line of code:

```
var inventory = dbInventory.Data
    .SqlQuery( sql )
    .OrderBy( m => m.isSold )
    .ThenBy( m => m.lotNumber )
    .ToList();
```

I this code for 4 pages on my website, the order is correct for the 3 out of the 4, for the 4th one, they dont want to go in order at all. For the one that is not working, all the isSold is false and they all have a lotNumber but its not returning the lotNumbers in order.

Please help.

Comment: It would help if you also included the definition of the model classes, my first thought is that you are trying to sort by numbers (the lotNumber) but they are actually strings, so .NET would sort them like strings, not numbers (i.e. 10 comes before 2)

Comment: `SqlQuery` returns `IEnumerable<T>`, hence the ordering part of the query is normal LINQ to Objects (has nothing to do with EF).

Comment: lotNumber is a string public string lotNumber { get; set; }

Comment: and isSold is bool `public bool isSold { get; set; }`

Comment: Please post the definition of `SqlQuery`. What is the type of `inventory`? What is the text of the generated SQL sent to your server? Are you certain you're using Linq-to-Entities and not Linq-to-Objects?

Comment: You say you're paging the data - but I don't see any paging in your Linq code (`Skip` and `Take`) - so where is that happening? What code is consuming `inventory`?

Comment: Could you please post what the order of the results are coming back as and explain how you expect them to come back?  I just want to make sure, that with "lotNumber" being a string, you aren't expecting "1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12" because as a string, that group of numbers would be sorted as "1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3"

Comment: @GregAndora I think you are right, Im going to try to convert my string to int in the order by clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my problem.

```
var inventory = dbInventory.Data.SqlQuery(sql).OrderBy(m => m.isSold).ThenBy(m => int.Parse(m.lotNumber)).ToList();
```